# Angular 1.4.14 <input> not show ng-model value after add item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have  which ng-model in ng-repeat of InvoiceLines
+ After add new Invoice Line first, i type some character in , ng-model and input value display well, InvoiceLines has 1 line.
+ After add new Invoice Line second, InvoiceLines has 2 line, first line  display blank but it ng-model keep old value which i typed
Here is my html

```
<div class="grid-row" ng-repeat="invoiceLine in EditInvoice.InvoiceLines track by $index" data-idx="{{$index + 1}}" ng-init="invoiceLine.LineNo = $index + 1 + ''">
    <div class="data-row row sortable-handle editable-row">
        <div class="row-index col" style="width:50px; float:left;">
            {{$index + 1}} 
        </div>
        <div class="col grid-static-col" style="width:150px; float:left;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control item-code" name="ItemCode[]" id="ItemCode_{{$index + 1}}" ng-model="invoiceLine.ItemCode">
                    <option value="">--Select --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col grid-static-col" style="width:300px; float:left;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description[]" id="Description_{{$index + 1}}" ng-model="invoiceLine.Description" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my addLine function

```
$scope.addLine = function() {
            var _invoiceLine = $scope.createInvoiceLineObject();

            $scope.EditInvoice.InvoiceLines.push(_invoiceLine);

        };
```

If i use

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description[]" id="Description_{{$index + 1}}" ng-model="invoiceLine.Description" ng-value="invoiceLine.Description"/>
```

of first line will keep old value which i typed after call function addLine

**Update**
Here is error if use ng-model only
[image: Here is error if use ng-model only]

It will be ok if use ng-model with ng-value
[image: It will be ok if use ng-model with ng-value]

Comment: don't use `ng-value` and `ng-model`. Just use `ng-model`

Answer (score 1):

You just need ng-model ,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description[]" id="Description_{{$index + 1}}" ng-model="invoiceLine.Description">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have error if use ng-model only

```
<form>  
  <div> header document here <div>  
  <div ng-repeat ...>  
    detail document here  
  </div>  
</form>
```

if I change to

```
<form>
  <div> header document here <div>  
</form>
<form>
  <div ng-repeat ...>  
    detail document here
  </div>  
</form>
```

it will be ok if use ng-model only.